# How can I check if the message author has an admin role using Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm building a Discord bot and I want to have an `if` statement that will only proceed if the message author has an administrator role in the guild.

I've tried having role-specific permissions, but this means that there will have to be the exact same name role on all servers that the bot is on.

How can I check if the message author has an admin role? (The role has the administrator permission.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Some of the following code must be modified to use in the newest major Discord.js version (v12 at the time of this edit) due to the implementation of Managers.*

There's really three different questions needed to be addressed here. They're all related, but each have different direct answers.

---

> How do I check if the message **author has an Admin role**?

- The [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/GuildMember) that sent a message is accessed via the [`Message#member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Message?scrollTo=member) property, as opposed to [`Message#author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Message?scrollTo=author) which returns a [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/User). Remember, a member has roles and permissions, *not* a user.
- A [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Collection) of a member's roles can be retrieved with [`GuildMember#roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles).
- You can search for a role two main ways:

  1. ID: [`Map#has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has)
  2. Property: [`Collection#find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Collection?scrollTo=find)

So, tying this all together:

```js
if (message.member.roles.has'roleIDHere')) console.log('User is an admin.');
```

*or*

```js
if (message.member.roles.find(role => role.name === 'Admin')) console.log('User is an admin.');
```

---

> How do I check if the message author's **role has the Administrator permission**?

- Again, we need to use the GuildMember from `Message#member`.
- And again, we need to use the `GuildMember#roles` collection.
- And... déjà vu... you can search through a Collection with `Collection#find()`.
- This time, you should specifically check [`Role#hasPermission()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Role?scrollTo=hasPermission) in the predicate function.

For example:

```js
if (message.member.roles.find(role => role.hasPermission('Administrator'))) console.log('User is an admin.');
```

You can apply this concept to any specific role, too.

---

**Best method for this situation...**

> How do I check if the message **author has the Administrator permission**?

- We continue to use `Message#member` to access the GuildMember.
- However, you can check *all* of a member's permissions at once via the [`GuildMember#hasPermission()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission) method.

Consider this short example:

```js
if (message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) console.log('User is an admin.');
```

Quick, right?

---

Make sure you check that the message your client receives is *not* a DM before attempting to check if the user is an Admin. `Message#member` is undefined when the message isn't sent in a guild, and trying to use properties of it will throw an error.

Use this condition, which will stop if the message is a DM:

```js
if (!message.guild) return;
```

Answer (score 3):

These answers seem outdated:

Use: `msg.member.roles.cache.has(roleID)`

Comment: This shows if it has a role of a specific id, not a role with admin permission. Also, "Try This" answers aren't really valuable on SO, since they don't show the person who asked the question how they can improve, it only shows them the answer to their question, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

On the GuildMember object, you have a [hasPermission](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission) function available.
So you can just do `member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')`

If you are interested in all the other strings, that are permission resolvable, you can find them in the [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS).

Comment: `if (message.content.startsWith('!kick') && member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {`
is what i did, but i got ReferenceError: member is not defined

Comment: You probably should post more of your code to see the context of this. And how you get / receive the actual member object.

Comment: client.on("message", (message) => {
                if (message.content == `${prefix}avatar` && member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
                    message.reply(message.author.avatarURL);
                }
            });
This is code. However I got same error as before.

Comment: In this context, you would need `message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')`