# Working on Discord bot kick + ban perms; it returns with error everytime

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am working on my ban and kick perms. I need to know how I would make it so that only this admin role can ban them. I want it to check with an if statement if they have the role, and if they do it would go along with the code, if not it would say: "You don't have permission to do this."

```
// ban
bot.on('message', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(config.prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'ban':
            if (!args[1]) message.channel.send("No person included.")

            const user = message.mentions.users.first();

            if (user) {
                const member = message.guild.member(user);

                if (member) {
                    member.ban({ ression: 'I don\'t make the rules.' }).then(() => {
                        message.reply(`I just banned @${user.tag}.`)
                    })
                } else {
                    message.reply("That user isn\`t in this server!");
                }
            }
            break;
    }
})
```

And my kick code:

```
bot.on('message', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(config.prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'kick':
            if (!args[1]) message.channel.send("No person included.")

            const user = message.mentions.users.first();

            if (user) {
                const member = message.guild.member(user);

                if (member) {
                    member.kick('You were kicked.').then(() => {
                        message.reply(`Sucessfully kicked @${user.tag}.`);
                    }).catch(err => {
                        message.reply(`I can\'t kick the member. (perms?)`);
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                } else {
                    message.reply("That user isn\`t in this server!");
                }
            }
            break;
    }
})
```

And my admin role numbers: 713787463331741726

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926998/how-can-i-check-if-the-message-author-has-an-admin-role-using-discord-js/56927113

Comment: You shouldn't have more than 1 of each event. This could cause problems such as memory leaks

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: @Syntle where do i check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether the author has a role by checking the role id.
For example:

```
if(!message.member.roles.cache.has('insert_ID_of_the_AdminRole')) return message.channel.send(`You can't use this command`)
```

Edit: (For v12 of discord.js)

Comment: Where would I put this?

Comment: I'd say right at the start, after the case 'kick' or case 'ban'